# Why doesn't JavaScript return the array I send it?

Tags: javascript

```js
class MyClass {
  returnSame(arr){
    return arr;
  }
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
console.log( [1] == myClass.returnSame([1]) );
```

I'm expecting the log to be true, but it's false. I'm sure this has to do with some fundamental principle of JavaScript that has managed to pass me by.

Why is this not true?

Comment: you'll see the same behavior with `[1] === [1]`. in other words, this has nothing to do with ecmascript-6

Comment: Thanks, of course. I should have known that one. With double, it still returns false though.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's double or triple. `[] !== []` and `[] != []` and `({} != {})` and so on.

Comment: I understand, so you're saying that there is no straight way to compare arrays without iteration. This looks like what I'm looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript Thanks for your help.

Comment: if the array values are primitive, and you don't care about sparseness, you can compare them as Strings.